# postgres - How to update the same record twice in a joined update query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write the following migration that drops the `conversations_users` table (which was a join table that included a `read_up_to` column) and copies the `read_up_to` information into the new `messages.read_by_user_ids` array. For every 1 message row there are at least 2 conversations_users rows, so this join is repeating messages. I expected the following expression to work, but it's only assigning one `user_id` to the `read_by_user_ids` array, and I'm guessing that's because the update isn't happening sequentially.

Result: 
`message_id: 1, read_by_user_ids: { 15 }`

Desired result: `message_id: 1, read_by_user_ids: { 15, 19 }`

```
UPDATE
      messages as m
    SET
      read_by_user_ids = CASE
        WHEN cu.read_up_to >= m.created_at THEN array_append(
          COALESCE(m.read_by_user_ids, '{}'),
          cu.user_id
        ) ELSE m.read_by_user_ids
      END
    FROM
      conversations_users cu
    WHERE
      cu.conversation_id = m.thread_id;
```

Comment: Aggregate your input to generate an array of user ids per message, in a sub-query for example, then your update statement only needs to update each target row once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on my phone, so apologies for untested typos.

As per my comment, aggregate the individual incoming user_ids into one array per conversation.  Then use `array_cat` to combine the two arrays.

This way you only need to do one update per target row.

I also noticed that you only want to update rows based on a date comparison, so I added that to the sub query I proposed.

```
UPDATE
  messages as m
SET
  read_by_user_ids = array_cat(
      COALESCE(m.read_by_user_ids, '{}'),
      cu.user_id_array
    )
FROM
(
  SELECT
    cu.conversation_id,
    array_agg(cu.user_id)   AS user_id_array
  FROM
    messages
  INNER JOIN
    conversations_users
      ON  cu.conversation_id  = m.thread_id
      AND cu.read_up_to      >= m.created_at
  GROUP BY
    cu.conversation_id
)
  cu
WHERE
  cu.conversation_id = m.thread_id;
```

There are many other options on how to generate the array in the sub-query.  Which is the most efficient will depend on the profile of your data, indexes, etc.  But the principle remains the same; updating the same row multiple times in a single statement doesn't work, you need to update each row once, with an array as the input.

Comment: Hey Mat, thanks a lot for the quick response. After your first comment I updated my query to the following and it seems to work.

`UPDATE
  messages
SET
  read_by_user_ids = (
    SELECT
      array_agg(user_id)
    FROM
      conversations_users
    WHERE
      conversations_users.conversation_id = messages.thread_id
      AND conversations_users.read_up_to >= messages.created_at
  );`

Comment: @DanielvanderMerwe - Your original post appended the new items to the existing array, this totally replaces the existing array.  If that's what you need, then all is good :)

Comment: It's a migration, so the all messages rows have a null `read_by_users_ids`, so it's fine for this. The original post appended because I was going row by row without aggregating the user ids.

Comment: @DanielvanderMerwe Feel free to upvote and/or accept if it helped ;)